# How to design this kind of html table

Tags: html, html-table

I would like to design a table one of the columns is complicated. Please check attachment. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: create another table inside td

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a simple example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

td {
  height: 30px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Land Phone</td>
    <td>Mobile</td>
    <td>No Vacancy Available</td>
    <td>
      <table style="border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
        <tr style="border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
          <td colspan="2" style="border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px">Preference</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
          <td style="width:50%; border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px">Boy/Girl</td>
          <td style="width:50%; border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px">IPCC/Direct Entry</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Dt. of Advt.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this help you.